# Getting information on ride requests in sandbox mode

Tags: uber-api

Using Uber's API, I managed to make a trip request, and then change it's status to accepted via the PUT command described in the docs.

However, if afterwards I make a GET request to fetch ride's attributes, I get status = accepted, but driver, eta, location and vehicle are null. Thus, I can't test that the whole flow works.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, once the trip in sandbox mode is set to status "Accepted" you should be able to see all those attributes. I just tested this myself and it worked fine.

The flow I followed was:

1) POST to https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests (with the proper params and auth headers) to create a sandbox trip

2) PUT to https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/{trip_UUID from step 1) with JSON body: `{"status": "accepted"}`

3) GET https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/current OR GET https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/{trip_UUID from step 1}

Could you provide some more details on the exact flow you followed?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [/v1/requests/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-details) endpoint documentation

> Note: The following fields are populated only when a trip is active:
>
> ```
> driver
> vehicle
> pickup
> destination
> ```

The meaning of the "accepted" status is:

> accepted  The Request has been accepted by a driver and is "en route"
>   to the start location (i.e. start_latitude and start_longitude).

I think by "trip is active" they mean the request status needs to be **in_progress**

> in_progress   The Request is "en route" from the start location to the
>   end location.

Try to change the status of the request to in_progress using the [PUT /v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/sandbox#section-resource) sandbox endpoint.
After this you should be able to get access to the driver, vehicle, pickup and destination fields.